# Xcode Objective C: Locking Landscape in a Toolbar after a gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, locking, uitoolbar

I want to create a toolbar that has a locking landscape method and an unlock. How can I go about this? 
I also just want it to display after a swipe gesture. I have the swipe gesture figured out but having trouble figuring out how to lock landscape after the user presses the button. 
It’s a app that has autorotate and want to keep it until the user wants to lock landscape. Where should I call or create this method? Do I need create another UIViewController and call it in the main one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override shouldAutorotate method on the UIViewController.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621419-shouldautorotate?changes=_3&language=objc

Here is the sample ViewController with one button to lock/unlock rotation.

```
@interface ViewController (){
    bool rotationLocked;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *lockButton;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)togleRotationLock:(id)sender {
    rotationLocked = !rotationLocked;
    if (rotationLocked)
        [_lockButton setTitle:@"Ulock Rotation" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [_lockButton setTitle:@"Lock Rotation" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (bool)shouldAutorotate{
    return !rotationLocked;
}

@end
```

Additionally you can override the supportedInterfaceOrientations if you need to set specific orientation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations?changes=_3&language=objc

Comment: Hi! Quick question. This only locks the container app but what about the device? How can I also lock the device orientation so that it does not crash when I pull the quick settings or pull down notifications?